# getLowlevelSourceObject in node.js

Tags: node.js

Node.js documentation of [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) has in the section for `readable.push` a reference

```
class SourceWrapper extends Readable {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);

    this._source = getLowlevelSourceObject();

    // Every time there's data, push it into the internal buffer.
    this._source.ondata = (chunk) => {
      // if push() returns false, then stop reading from source
      if (!this.push(chunk))
        this._source.readStop();
      };

      // When the source ends, push the EOF-signaling `null` chunk
      this._source.onend = () => {
        this.push(null);
      };
    }
    // _read will be called when the stream wants to pull more data in
    // the advisory size argument is ignored in this case.
    _read(size) {
    this._source.readStart();
  }
}
```

which gives access to the method `this._source.ondata` (needed in the example below), but there is no mention on how to get the low lever source object, neither can I find any function with that name from the Node.js source code - excluding the documentation files.

I am trying to port a legacy application written in CoffeeScript from Node.js v0.10 to v10 and currently I am not able to trace what this part is supposed to do (the used `FakeSocket` class is fully here)

```
class FakeSocket extends Stream
  constructor: (handler, options) ->
    super(options)

    @writeBuffer = new Buffer('')
    @writable = true
    @readable = true
    @needDrain = false

    @_writableState = {}

  emitData: (@buffer) ->
    self = @
    try
      @ondata(@buffer, 0, @buffer.length)
    catch err
      console.log 'error on ondata',err
      console.log err.stack

  write: (data, encoding) ->
    unless data instanceof Buffer
      data = new Buffer(data.toString())

    combinedBuffer = new Buffer(@writeBuffer.length + data.length)
    @writeBuffer.copy(combinedBuffer)
    data.copy combinedBuffer, @writeBuffer.length
    @writeBuffer = combinedBuffer
    @emit('write')
```

First of all I do not know how to get the underlying low level source object nor if it needed. Does anyone know how the API has changed in order to write the same in v10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of struggle I have deduced that `ondata` method of Stream can be replaced by emitting an event:

```
// Generic buffer
const buffer = Buffer.from('loremipsum')

// Old Node.js v0.10 API that used to work
const stream = new Stream()
stream.ondata(buffer)

// Node.js v10 compatible
const stream = new Stream()
stream.emit('data', bufferToEmit)
```

even though the documentation still mentions the `this._source.ondata`